# ssh connection refused : tryhackme Learn Linux walkthrough

Tags: ssh, connection

I was so far searching the answers on the internet,but nothing helped me

**the ssh connection is being refused at port 22.**

**even when i started services : ssh , openssh-server,openssh-client**

can't figure it out what the actual problem behind this....

In **tryhackme.com** we can just deploy some target machines, so that we pratically learn so far.

[please go through][1]

**[1]: *https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVoM4.png***

the ip address within the user **shiba1** is the **tryhackme** Virtual machine...

u can find the following room through this link

***https://tryhackme.com/room/zthlinux***

And finally Very Thank you...
I was searching for this thing for 4 days now.Hope u can help me!

Answer (score 1):

That is simply because :

1. you haven't connected to their network using openvpn,OR
2. you haven't deploy the machine in task 1. I know, I missed it too!

Answer (score 1):

I was pulling my hair out on this one too. Like llmi Kalam said, you have to Deploy the Machine! It's a green button at the top right corner of Task 1. I didn't see it until I went back to it a third time. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to connect to tryhackme virtual network using openvpn.

You can download the ovpn configuration file from [here](https://tryhackme.com/access).
Use the flowing command in the terminal.

```
sudo openvpn <file-name>.ovpn
```

Then start the machine and use the ssh command.