# Authentication error while performing a ssh connection on Tryhackme

Tags: ssh, connection

I have been searching for this problem for so long, but I cant seem to get a positive result, I am new to pentesting and so I am doing some tasks on tryhackme for learning the basics of Linux and so when I try to connect to an ssh server :

```
ssh shiba1@10.8.150.23                
The authenticity of host '10.8.150.23 (10.8.150.23)' can't be  established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 
SHA256:5mSp6dwM2HeSewbWzIVJ2GV4bRUmbrdS0ZX8qMRPjfU.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no   /[fingerprint])? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/chota/.ssh/known_hosts).
shiba1@10.8.150.23's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
shiba1@10.8.150.23's password:
```

it gives me an authentication error(even though I am typing the correct password which is shiba1) btw this question is not a duplicate of [ssh connection refused : tryhackme Learn Linux walkthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162888/ssh-connection-refused-tryhackme-learn-linux-walkthrough)
Any help would be appreciated

Btw, you can find the room at the following link:

https://tryhackme.com/room/zthlinux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it gives me an authentication error

Before that, it gives you an issue with `/home/chota/.ssh/known_hosts`.
I would start by checking the permissions of `/home/chota/.ssh` and `known_hosts`, to see why the ssh process is not able to modify that file.

Than I can check if the authentication error persists.

Comment: i checked the permissions and changed the ssh configuration file in .ssh directory but it still gave me the same error...

Comment: @Justaus3r OK. Could you edit your question with the content of your `~/.ssh/config` file?