# Can't ssh to tryhackme server

Tags: ssh

I am new to pentesting and so I am doing some tasks on tryhackme for learning the basics of Linux and so when I try to connect to an ssh server :

```
ssh shiba1@10.8.150.23                
The authenticity of host '10.8.150.23 (10.8.150.23)' can't be  established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 
SHA256:5mSp6dwM2HeSewbWzIVJ2GV4bRUmbrdS0ZX8qMRPjfU.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no   /[fingerprint])? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts).
shiba1@10.8.150.23's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
shiba1@10.8.150.23's password:
```

it gives me an authentication error(even though I am typing the correct password which is shiba1) btw this question is not a duplicate of [ssh connection refused : tryhackme Learn Linux walkthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162888/ssh-connection-refused-tryhackme-learn-linux-walkthrough)
Does anyone know what's the problem.

Btw, you can find the room at the following link:

https://tryhackme.com/room/zthlinux

home/user/.ssh/known_hosts stores the host names

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You can try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the ip given when you deploy the machine.then ssh to the server and be sure to connect to tryhackme openvpn.and i suggest this rrom if you are a beginner :https://tryhackme.com/room/linux2

Comment: thanks i used my ip instead of the machine i was deploying

Answer (score 1):

1.Make sure you have connected to tryhackme's openvpn .

2.Check if u good network connection.

3.some room in tryhackme may take some time like 5 minutes to get booted up.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have connected to TryHackMe openvpn by downloading the configuration file and using the command:

```
sudo openvpn (configuration file path)
```

Make sure you have terminated any already running machines and clicking deploy from the room you are working on.

Don't forget to make sure you have the caps lock off.
I have already completed that room on TryHackMe without any issues. So the issue is most likely from your end.

GL

Comment: Check this room on how to connect to openvpn: [link](https://tryhackme.com/room/openvpn)

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for such an error are multiple (probably the last one):

- Locked password
- PermitRootLogin variable set to "No"
- AllowUsers not set to otheruser
- You typed your password wrong since the keyboard might switch
  .
  .
  .

Can you show us the log of :

```
ssh -vvv shiba1@10.8.150.23
```